# Zend Framework 1.2 - Configuration by modules

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have some plugins in zend framework and at the same time I have an application with various modules, I would like to know how to load plugins without all run on each request.

In module admin I have a function in bootstrap file:

```
public function _initPlugins() {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_SecurityCheck());
    }
```

In module affiliates I have a function in bootstrap file:

```
public function _initPlugins() {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new Affiliates_Plugin_SecurityCheck());
    }
```

I just want to load plugins and settings per module and not in all modules. How can you do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace standard `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules` resource, which load modules.

For this:

1. Create `Your_Application_Resource_ModulesCustom`, which extends from `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules` and disable automatic call of `_initPlugins` for modules.
2. When you determine, which module must be loaded, you should manually call `_initPlugins` for this module.

Comment: Look to my code in application.ini :

`
admin.resources.db.params.dbname = "admin"

affiliates.resources.db.params.dbname = "affiliates"`


I am trying to indicate that the module "admin", use the database "admin" and the module "affiliates" use database "affiliates".

Comment: I meant `application/configs/application.ini`

Comment: in the past I used this way:
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Admin_Plugin_SecurityCheck"

Look in: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

Comment: What event listen your plugins?

Comment: So if I have 500 plugins, I have to add that logic? Where is the concept of modularity? This is the wrong way, I just want certain settings to be loaded based on the module.

Comment: Yes, this a wrong way. Good way - using custom implementation of `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules`.

Comment: I have only a private project on bitbucket, i can share with u but u need to give me ur mail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60570/discussion-between-maximkou-and-joao-silva).